# How to set up a score board using SFML and Box2D in C++

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

I want to set up a scoreboard for these two players (Pikachu)

[image: game screen]

My questions are:

1. how to detect when the ball touches the ground?
2. how to setup an object that can change during the game?

like the two in this picture:

[image: others' game screen]

I'm very new to SFML and Box2D, so even if I try to read the source code to see what I can use to implement things above, I still have no idea.

Can anyone give me some clues?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, seeing the code from which you're working would give us a chance. #1 could easily be done by watching the y coordinate of the ball.

Answer (score 0):

To create a scoreboard similar to the one in the image provided you can put text on the screen that holds the current score of the players and then placing it in the position where you want the score to be placed on the screen. In SFML this would be done by creating a [sf::Text](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php) object.

To answer your other questions.

> 1.how to detect when the ball touches the ground

A simple way of doing this would be to check the Y value of the coordinates of the ball and from that determining if the ball is touching the ground.

> 2.how to setup an object that it can change during the game.

I am unsure what you mean by this.